# "Expert rating" for puzzles

Tags: discussion, voting

I haven't been very active on Puzzling generally, but recently wanted to collect some nice little puzzles for my website, and noticed how unreliable the voting system is. There are people on PSE which consistently put lots of effort in creating smart, different, well presented puzzles and deservedly receive fair number of votes for them, but there are also many simple questions, which rarely offer something new, but get many votes nonetheless. I've noticed this happens most often with riddles, usually the ones which take more time to get solved.
I was thinking that maybe a new (or second) rating system, which puts emphasis on votes by the more prominent puzzlers in the community may be a good idea. This way it will be easier for people looking for original content to find it more easily.

P.S. Even though I'm not big fan of them, I don't want to downplay riddles in my post. Some of them are based on nice subtle hints and/or offer interesting twists, @Roland's "5 Letter Word" and @IAminPLS' "Seven Friends" coming to mind.

Comment: Did I break the record for most downvoted question on META?

Comment: No, that would be [this](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2849/a-private-and-offensive-chatroom). :)

Comment: @Mithrandir you guys are relentless here.

Answer (score 5):

We already have the [quarterly best-of](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).

Comment: Thank you, I found some hidden gems in these threads.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at this query on data.stackexchange:

[Best Questions: Highest ratio of upvotes to views](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/421254)

One problem is that when a puzzles hits the Hot Network Questions (HNQ) list, it gets *way* more views than other puzzles.  If even a fraction of those translate to upvotes, a puzzle can gain a significant number of upvotes.

The above query tries to filter out HNQ-upvoted puzzles by looking for questions that have the most upvotes per view.  You can adjust the parameters for the minimum number of votes and the minimum number of views.

Comment: I've noticed that votes come at a much slower rate once you get over few thousand views, but that's still a very useful link, thank you!